# why is the color and texture of 3d file missing in arcgis scene?

Tags: collada, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-net

i am trying to build arcgis scene with my custom 3d models with *ModelSceneSymbol* but when the model finally loaded(.dae format) it appeared pure white when i explicitly designed it red, also most of the other formats like .fbx,obj etc. don't seem to get rendered on the scene, can anyone give me a solution for the color part alone, i am using vectary for 3d model creation btw